# Nodes can't resume after out-of-disk failure: Assert_failure vendors/irmin-pack/pack.ml:270:6

Tags: node, archive-node

- 2 Nodes on same host : one archive-mode mainnet and a babylonnet baker
- both failed when machine ran out of disk space
- cleaned-up space but restarting them shows:

```
Jan 30 13:43:38 - validator.block: Validation of block BKjHmnynhftFBaG98rjG32UNFUvC5uRhJh6FbnKmwWT51L8MEWW failed
Jan 30 13:43:38 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-30T18:43:38-00:00, treated in 21us, completed in 333ms , 
Jan 30 13:43:38 - validator.block: "Assert_failure vendors/irmin-pack/pack.ml:270:6"
Jan 30 13:43:38 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator):
Jan 30 13:43:38 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Error:
Jan 30 13:43:38 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   "Assert_failure vendors/irmin-pack/pack.ml:270:6"
Jan 30 13:43:38 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: 
Jan 30 13:43:38 - validator.peer: Worker crashed [validator-peer_240]:
```

For both nodes `tezos-admin-client list rejected blocks` says:

```
No invalid blocks.
```

And `tezos-admin-client unmark all invalid blocks` does nothing.

```
 $ uname -srvmpio
Darwin 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Sun Dec  1 18:59:03 PST 2019; root:xnu-4903.278.19~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 Macmini8,1 Darwin
```

It's the multinetwork-node from *a while ago*:

```
 $ tezos-node --version
307cae9e (2019-10-11 15:45:11 +0200)
```

PS:
I had seen somewhere `dune exec -- vendors/index/fix.exe ...`, there does not seem to be such an executable definition in `vendors/index/..`

Comment: I tried with today's `master` branch and same error.

Comment: We just hit this error too. No resolution.